# limit superior is a cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If
> $$(\forall\varepsilon)(\forall m)(0<\varepsilon\land
>  m\in\mathbb{N}\implies(\exists n)(n\in\mathbb{N}\land m\leq n\land
>  |x_n-a|<\varepsilon)),$$ then $a$ is called a **cluster point** of
> $(x_n)$.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $\limsup x_n:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\sup_{n\leq k}x_k)$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)$. I have already shown this for $\limsup x_n\in\{\infty,-\infty\}$. Suppose $\limsup x_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $0<\varepsilon$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\limsup x_n\leq\sup_{m\leq k}x_n.$$
Thus $\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<\sup_{m\leq k}x_k$. There exists $m\leq\ell$ such that $\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<x_\ell$.

How can I show that $x_\ell<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$? Or else, how can I use $x_\ell$ to find an $x_{\ell'}$ for which the inequalities hold?

Edit:

Clearly, $\limsup x_n<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$. Hence there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\sup_{n_0\leq k}x_k<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon.$$
How can I use this fact together with what I have shown above to find an integer $k\leq m$ for which
$$\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<x_k<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$$
holds?

Comment: Note: It is substantially more legible and common practice to write: $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \forall m \in \mathbb N\ \exists n \in \mathbb N, m \leq n \land |x_n -a| < \epsilon$. You can put the range that your variables quantify over next to the quantifier. It makes it much clearer.

Comment: Another note: provided $\limsup x_n \in \{\pm \infty\}$, it cannot be a cluster point by your definition, since $|x - \infty| = \infty \not < \epsilon$. There is an alternative definition you can use for $\pm \infty$ as cluster points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $c \in \mathbb N$.

$\limsup x_n = \inf_n \sup_{m \geq n} x_m$, thus $\limsup x_n + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound for the monotonically decreasing sequence $(\sup_{m \geq n} x_m)_n$, thus there exists some $N$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$, $\sup_{m \geq n} x_m < \limsup x_n + \epsilon$. We can WLOG take $N \geq c$, by just replacing it by $\max(N,c)$.

$\limsup x_n$ is also a lower bound for the monotonically decreasing sequence $(\sup_{m \geq n} x_m)_n$, so $\sup_{m \geq N} x_m > \limsup x_n - \epsilon$. Thus since the $\sup$ is the least upper bound, there exists some $\ell \geq N \geq c$ s.t. $x_\ell > \limsup x_n - \epsilon$. Then $x_\ell \leq \sup_{m \geq N} x_n < \limsup x_n + \epsilon$. Hence $\limsup x_n - \epsilon < x_\ell < \limsup x_n + \epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: This is true but what is the relation between this $N$ and my $\ell$? It follows that $x_m<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$ but how to show that $\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<x_m$? I am having difficulty finding an integer $k\geq m$ such that $\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<x_k<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$.

Comment: @guam I finished the proof for you.

Comment: With the definition of cluster points that I am using, some $0<\varepsilon$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ have to be fixed first. Then I have to prove that there exists $k\geq m$ for which $\limsup x_n-\varepsilon<x_k<\limsup x_n+\varepsilon$. It is not clear to me why your $\ell$ (or even $N$) is greater than or equal to the fixed $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @guam Added in more detail.

Comment: perfect thank you!